# Add hyphen between 2 spans, but only when left span is a single line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Sorry about the title, can't think of a better way of describing this issue.

I have a container, that includes 2 spans, the content of each span can differ so can't solely rely on media queries here. Sometimes the text on the left span can be 20 characters, sometimes 100 for example.

I want it that when the left span is on a single line it adds a hyphen between the left and right span elements and when the left span breaks onto a new line, it removes the hyphen.

### Component

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 44px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
`;

const Text = styled.p`
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
`;

const Left = styled.span`
  white-space: pre-line;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: green;
  &::after {
    content: " - ";
  }
`;

const Right = styled.span`
  background: blue;
`;

const Content = ({ rightText, leftText }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Wrapper>
        <Text>
          <Left>{leftText}</Left>
          <Right>{rightText}</Right>
        </Text>
      </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

You can see here, one the 1st instance it has a hyphen to the right of the text, but I don't want the hyphen there, but I do on the other 2.

[image]

Is there a way via CSS or JS to only add the hyphen when the left text is on a single line

[image: Edit cranky-chaplygin-gdjgjk]

Comment: Have you tried putting a dash in a pseudo element :before or :after and placing it between the boxes at all? That will keep the dash in one spot regardless of text in the left box.

Comment: It's not the position of the hyphen that's the issue, it's that it renders at all. The designers preference is not to add the hyphen once it breaks onto a new line

Comment: That is an odd request to have it and then not just because of height. It looks like the answer from @Akil Ashokan would be the way to go for sure or similar. Definitely try to calculate the height and font to detect if it is two lines and then remove the dash.

Comment: If you haven't set the height of an element, the height of a single line element (not wrapped) will be *spacings + borders* **+ line-height in pixels**. When that height gets exceeded you got a 'wrap'. Will need some JS to monitor, I guess.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Yep will definitely need JS to monitor on both load and resize for sure. At that point though I would just tell them to remove the dash from the design.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula sure, but I won't interfere with someone elses design requirements based on a snippet. Might be millions of dollars involved having the hyphen, who knows...

Comment: @RenevanderLende That is fair. If it is alot of money for that hyphen sign me up!

Comment: If I had it my way, I'd opt for @OMGDrAculas solution. The designer has decided to go down the route of shifting the right content below the left content at a certain breakpoint and using a text overflow on the left content so it stays on one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like comparing the paragraph's innerheight with the fontsize.

say para.clientHeight > (computed fontSize of paragraph) + padding then that means the paragraph is now multiline, remove psudo class if its the case.